# How can I ensure that phone app traffic is using HTTPS?

Tags: tls, android, phone

When I access a website, I know just by looking at the URL whether it's HTTPS or HTTP.

If I'm using an app on my phone, I cannot see this. So if say the app wants me to enter a password in to create an account (or enter some other private information), how do I know that they're passing my data via HTTPS and therefore can not be intercepted?

I use Android but I would like to know for iOS and Windows Phone too.

Comment: OK didn't see that question. Happy to close this one

Comment: You can agree to close it by clicking. ;-)

Comment: For iOS, HTTPS is **mandatory** as of Jan 2017.